# output for a texteild is zero rather then an actual result

Tags: ios, double, uialertview, string-formatting, textfield

This is a strange output, I seem to trigger the alert view each time, and the value for `num1` would be `0.50` which is fine.

When I click calculate the alert field is triggered, and what's more `num1` is set to `0.00`, and the `tcost` which is the total cost seems to always be `0`.

This has never happened before.

The type out of output should be something such as a `0.23` etc.. for `tcost` the reason for the alert field is so i can trap if a user has not filled a field out.

```
(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (textField1) {

        NSString *txt = self.textField1.text;
        double num1 = [txt doubleValue];
        double tCost = num1/100;

        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
        [numberFormatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
        NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tCost]];

        self.textField1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numberString];
    }
}

(IBAction)calculateCost:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *rate = self.textField1.text;
    NSString *wat = self.textField2.text;
    NSString *hours = self.textField3.text;
    NSString *Days = self.textField4.text;

    long double num1 = [rate doubleValue];
    long double num2 = [wat doubleValue];
    long double num3 = [hours doubleValue];
    long double num4 = [Days doubleValue];

    //double num12 = num1 /10000;

    double appKw = num2 / 1000;
    double costKwph = appKw *num1;

    double tCost = ((num4 * num3) * costKwph);

    if (num2 == 0||  num1 <= 0.000|| num3 == 0 || num4 == 0) {
        self.textField5.text = 0;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"oops" message:@"you must fill in all fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

        [alert show];
    }

    tCost = tCost / 100;

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:4];


    NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tCost]];

    self.textField5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numberAsString];
}
```

Comment: if i remove the if statement in textFieldDidEndEditing and including code, the submit button works fine. i think it may lie in problems with nsnumberformatter /double and calculations to trap zero in the alert view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (textField == self.textField1) {
      NSNumberFormatter *nFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
      [nFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
      self.textField1.text = [nFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:     [self.textField1.text doubleValue] / 100]];
    }
```

You can not extract float from currency, hence why the result in textField5 is zero. so forma the above to output to a corresponding label so the user can see the formatted string like so.

```
if (textField == self.textField1) {
    NSNumberFormatter *nFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    self.labeltest.text = [nFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: [self.textField1.text doubleValue] /100]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your textField in NSNumber, for example:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * num1 = [f numberFromString:self.textField1.text];
```

Comment: NSNumberFormatter *nFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
      
      [nFormatter setNumberStyle:     NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
  
      [nFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
  
  
      NSNumber * num11 = [nFormatter     numberFromString:self.textField1.text];
      [nFormatter setRoundingMode:     NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
       
      NSString *numberString = [nFormatter stringFromNumber:    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num11]];
  
      
      self.textField1.text = [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@",numberString];
     }

Comment: sorry im not sure how to add comments in a formatted way, but i tried your idea i recieved a redfine type error and it would not compile